# Address Book iOS : Contact name from string

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, abaddressbooksource

I am trying to automatically add contact to the iOS address book from my app, where the name of the contact is from a NSString. I have tried to figure it out (see code under), but It didn't work. It works to add contacts with the first code I have provided (I have the save code and stuff), but I would like to add contact from string that may vary, not just a name that can't.

```
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,@"Davis11", &error);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"Scott", &error);
```

I have also tried this code, with no luck:

```
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty,fName, &error);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, lName, &error);
```

Comment: If it doesn't work with `fName` and `lName` then maybe you are not setting `fName` and `lName` correctly. Show the _whole_ code, including the code that does that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine, but you have forgotten to call `ABAddressBookAddRecord` and `ABAddressBookSave`. Nothing will happen until you do that. What you've got is a person floating around loose. You have to *put* that person into the address book if you want it to *be* part of the address book.

Also, please remember to do memory management. Here's a complete example (but error checking is omitted from the example! do not do that in real life):

```
CFErrorRef err = nil;
ABAddressBookRef adbk = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, &err);
ABRecordRef snidely = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(snidely, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Snidely", nil);
ABRecordSetValue(snidely, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"Whiplash", nil);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(adbk, snidely, nil);
ABAddressBookSave(adbk, nil);
if (snidely) CFRelease(snidely);
if (adbk) CFRelease(adbk);
```

Comment: Here's a complete example with actual authorization checking and so forth: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch18p713addressBook/ch31p973addressBook/ViewController.m